# How do I scroll to the first error when all my checkbox inputs have the same name?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, scroll, formik, ionic7

I'm using React 18, Ionic 7, and Formik 2.4.3.  I have a component that I use when I want to scroll to the top the location of an error

```
export const getFieldErrorNames = (formikErrors) => {
  const transformObjectToDotNotation = (obj, prefix = '', result = []) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
      const value = obj[key]
      if (!value) return

      const nextKey = prefix ? `${prefix}.${key}` : key
      if (typeof value === 'object') {
        transformObjectToDotNotation(value, nextKey, result)
      } else {
        result.push(nextKey)
      }
    })

    return result
  }

  return transformObjectToDotNotation(formikErrors)
}

const ScrollToFieldError = ({ submitCount, errors }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fieldErrorNames = getFieldErrorNames(errors)
    if (fieldErrorNames.length <= 0) return

    const elements = document.getElementsByName(fieldErrorNames[0])
    const element = elements[0]
    if (!element) return

    // Scroll to first known error into view
    element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' })
  }, [submitCount])

  return null
}

export default ScrollToFieldError
```

In my Formik form, I use the component like so

```
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    selectedIds: Yup.array().min(1, 'Select at least one item').required('Select at least one item')
  })
    ...

    <Formik
      enableReinitialize={true}
      initialValues={{ selectedIds }}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={(values) => {
        handleSaveAndContinue(values.selectedIds)
      }}
    >
      {(formikProps) => (
        <form onSubmit={formikProps.handleSubmit}>
          <ScrollToFirstError submitCount={formikProps.submitCount} errors={formikProps.errors} />
          {formikProps.touched.selectedIds && formikProps.errors.selectedIds ? (
            <div>{formikProps.errors.selectedIds}</div>
          ) : null}
          <IonList>
            ...
            {items.map((item) => (
              <IonItem key={item.id}>
                <IonCheckbox
                  name='selectedIds'
                  value={item.id}
                  
                >{`${item.name}`}</IonCheckbox>
              </IonItem>
            ))}
          </IonList>
          <IonButton aria-lael='Save And COntinue' type='submit'>
            Submit
          </IonButton>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
```

The issue is when I click my "Submit" button without checking anything, although my error message properly appears, the scroll to the top of the page does not occur.  I would like to keep my component, ScrollToFirstError, as generic as possible as I use it on other types of forms, so curious if there's a way to adjust my existing form to get the functionality to work.  An example with the problem is here -- https://stackblitz.com/edit/an5yjh-c2pz8v?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FScrollToFirstError.tsx,src%2Fcomponents%2FMyForm.tsx,package-lock.json

Comment: Although I have added an answer. Creating a component isn't the best way to handle this behaviour. It isn't a component at all. It's more like a hook just meant to scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the values of `formikProps.submitCount` and `formikProps.errors` are updated separately. Check the process [here](https://formik.org/docs/guides/form-submission).

They don't update at the same time. The useEffect of `ScrollToFieldError` only has the dependency of `submitCount` and not for `errors`. So when it detects a change for submit, the error array isn't updated yet. Adding `errors` in dependency will fix your issue.

```
const ScrollToFieldError = ({ submitCount, errors }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fieldErrorNames = getFieldErrorNames(errors);
    if (fieldErrorNames.length <= 0) return;

    const elements = document.getElementsByName(fieldErrorNames[0]);
    const element = elements[0];
    if (!element) return;

    // Scroll to first known error into view
    element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
  }, [submitCount, errors]);

  return null;
};
```